# How to get rid of flickring while changing iframe source dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to build a iframe slideshow. I have 7 webpages named event1.html to event7.html. I'm using setInterval to change the source of iframe every 1 second. But while changing, it is happening sudden and flickering. How can i get rid of this flickring and add some effects.
I don't want to use JQuery.

Here is my code

```
var i=1;
function initialize()
{
    iframeh = document.getElementById("eventholder");
    iframeh.src="event1.html";
    setInterval(function(){i=changesrc(i)},1000);
}
function changesrc(i)
{
    iframeh.src="event"+i+".html";
    if(i%7==0)
        i=0;
    return i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i can able to get rid of that flickering.

I used two divs and placed iframes in that. Initially i made the second div invisible and loaded second frame in that. after some time i'm making the second div visible and first div invisible and loading third frame in that and so on using javascript.